# eclipse.exe doesnt open on clicking

Tags: java, eclipse, windows

I updated my OS to Win 8.1 quite recently. Ever since then I'm unable to open my Eclipse. I even downloaded a fresh zip file off the net and tried. It didnt open. 
I found a fellow with similar issue in another forum.He finally found his problem to be that his PATH var had be changed to point to the 32 bit version of his 64 bit system. How would I know if thats whats happened to me?

And if thats not the case, what might be the problem I'm facing? My system has the latest versions of JDK n JRE. [Java 8 Update 31, JDK 7 Update 51 (64-bit)]

Comment: Do you have an error message?  A log file?

Comment: can you try to run the eclipse.exe from the command line prompt and check what is the displayed error?

Comment: No error message of any sort. No response from the system whatsoever

Comment: what is the command to run eclipse.exe from the command line prompt?

Comment: Press `Windows` + `R` buttons, then  type `cmd`, then in the command prompt window explore to your eclipse folder via `cd` command, example: `cd C:\Folder\Of\Eclipse`, then type `eclipse.exe`

Comment: Yes, Done. No errors. In response the prompt came once more. The blue round symbol came for some time next to the cursor and then....nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to eclipse.exe and give -vm "c:\path\to\jdk\bin\javaw.exe" command line argument. You may test this in a dos console and even give java.exe to see all startup messages.